# Next Step After Finding Eigenvalues of Transformation Matrix T?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, transformation

I've successfully determined the eigenvalues of the transformation matrix (T = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 5 & -10 \\ 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}). Now I'm wondering about the next logical step in this process. Could someone guide me on how to find (if possible) the bases for the corresponding eigenspaces? I'd greatly appreciate any insights or steps to take from this point forward. Here's my attempt:

$$\left( T-\lambda_{1} I\right)  \mathbf{v} =0$$ where $\lambda_{1} = 1$, so we have:

$$\begin{pmatrix}1-1&0&0&0\\ 0&1-1&5&-10\\ 1&0&2-1&0\\ 1&0&0&3-1\end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{gathered}v_{1}\\ v_{2}\\ v_{3}\\ v_{4}\end{gathered} \right)  =0$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do this in *exactly the same way* you would for finding the basis of a nullspace... just that the you are finding the basis of the nullspace of $(A-\lambda I)$.  You should have had plenty of practice doing this already by this point if you are talking about eigenvalues.

Comment: @JMoravitz I edited my post, is that a good first attempt?

Comment: I wouldn't call that an attempt yet.  This is merely the setup for an attempt.

Comment: @JMoravitz I have understood what the basis vectors are for $\lambda_1$. My question is about how to obtain bases for the eigenspaces corresponding to $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$.

For $\lambda_2$, the basis of the eigenspace is the vector $$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ 5 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{array}\right)$$. And for $\lambda_3$, the basis of the eigenspace is the vector $$\left(\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -5 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{array}\right)$$.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.  The words you used make it sound like you don't know how to continue the problem, but the values you show are precisely the answer to the problem you say you don't know how to solve.  What additional help do you still need?

Comment: Also, to be clear... you used the wording "**the** *basis of the eigenspace is the vector...*" which might be interpreted that you believe there is only one correct answer, but there are in fact infinitely many ways to describe the eigenspace.  It is more correct to say "**a** *basis of the eigenspace is...*"

Comment: @JMoravitz How do they get those bases for $\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_3$? One of them is merely the third column vector here, and the other is the fourth column vector, but how is that a basis of the eigenspace? $$\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 5 & -10 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: For the eigenvalue $\lambda =1$, look at $A-\lambda I$ which is $A-I$ here.  Row reduce that.  You are left with a matrix.  Interpret that matrix as a system of equations describing the values of a vector $v$ such that $(A-\lambda I)v=0$.  Make a choice of free-variables to simplify the representations.  With regards to $\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ the process is the same.  It is a fluke that they happened to correspond to the columns here before row reduction.

Comment: Again, knowing and understanding how to find the nullspace of a matrix should have been learned and mastered several lessons before eigenvalues and eigenspaces.  If you are not comfortable with that, then go back to those lessons and exercises before continuing with your current lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&5&-10\\1&0&2&0\\1&0&0&3\end{bmatrix}$

$\det(A-\lambda I) = \lambda^4-7\lambda^3+17\lambda^2-17\lambda+6=(\lambda-3)(\lambda-2)(\lambda-1)^2$ so we have eigenvalues $1, 1, 2, 3$

The eigenspace for $\lambda_2=2$ will simply be the nullspace of $A-\lambda_2 I$.  To find this, look at the row reduction of $A-\lambda_2 I$

$\text{rref}\left(\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&0&0\\0&-1&5&-10\\1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&-5&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$

Interpreting this, this says that if $v = \begin{bmatrix}v_1\\v_2\\v_3\\v_4\end{bmatrix}$ were a vector such that $(A - \lambda_2)v = 0$ (*which would mean that $Av = \lambda_2 v$*) that it must be such that $\begin{cases}v_1=0\\v_2-5v_3=0\\v_4=0\\0=0\end{cases}$

This means, if we were to parametrize this by letting $v_3$ be some scalar... let's call it $t$, that we have $v_1=0, v_2=5t, v_3=t, v_4=0$, in other words that $\begin{bmatrix}0\\5\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ works as a basis for the eigenspace for $\lambda = 2$.

The fact that it just so happens that this was one of the columns of the original matrix is a fluke and you should not expect this to happen again in other problems.

This process is, again as pointed out in the comments, no different than what you should have learned and already been performing when being introduced to nullspaces in the previous chapter(s) before ever being shown the word "eigenspace."